# Pattern using rep and seq

Tags: r, seq, rep

I'm working on a practice test for a final exam I have coming up, and this is one of the questions:

> Create the following vector by using **both** the `rep` and `seq` functions:
>
> > x = -7, -7, -7, 0, 7, 7, 14, 14, 14, 14

I cannot wrap my head around how to create this pattern. Here's what I have so far, but I'm not sure this is the most elegant way to accomplish it:

```
rep(seq(-7, 14, 7), c(3,1,2,4))
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: hard to think of an obvious way to improve on your answer ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your solution looks elegant enough to me. In your solution, you may want to add a few things to increase readability-

```
rep(seq(from = -7, to = 14, by = 7), times = c(3,1,2,4))
```